# How to export daily disk space usage?

Tags: linux, excel, shell, csv, diskspace

I am new to scripting.

Is it possible to export the disk space usage of a linux server to an excel shell(.csv) sheet daily ? 
If so, what will be the scripting for that?

Comment: Why don't you just export the disk space usage as is and then parse / format the resulting file with Excel / VBA to your liking / needs?

Comment: I wanna make it as a job which has to run daily. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: So, what's stopping you? https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2012/02/20/cron-script-for-checking-disk-space/ AND http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/comment-page-1/ were among the first google results. That's all you need to schedule a daily cron job for exporting disk usage. Afterwards, you can format / edit the resulting files in Excel (automate that VBA). Done. If you don't like this script or the result then just google some more. There are hundreds of scripts like this on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` to parse `df` result:

Assuming `;` is your csv separator, then:

```
df -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2";"$3";"$4}'
```

gives:

```
24G;5.4G;18G
```

In a full script with the date:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEPARATOR=","
SIZES=`df -h | awk -v SEP="$SEPARATOR" 'FNR == 2 {print SEP$2SEP$3SEP$4}'`
echo `date +%Z-%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`"$SIZES" >> test.csv
```

Comment: Is it possible to have like SIZE in a column and USED SPACE in one column and AVAILABLE SPACE in another?

Comment: It is not what I did? If you open the result file with Excel you will have respectively one column DATE, then one column SIZE, then USED SPACE and then AVAILABLE SPACE. Did you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it and the result was observed in a single cell. Not in separate columns as you were saying :(

Comment: Ok that's probably because your CSV separator char is not `;`. You have to find your separator char and then replace the `;`.

Comment: My OS Redhat (remote server) and I use MS Excel to read CSV files.

Comment: Ok create a new csv file with Excel and then writte anything in the first two cells. Then read the csv with a text editor and look at the separator char

Comment: My CSV separator is ,
Now it is working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using shell sctript you can write it as below.
And then you can schedule your script by using crontabs.

Script:-

```
#!/bin/bash

DDATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
{
TIME=$(date)
DISK=$(df -h)

echo $DDATE

cat <<-EOF

>>>>Disk space<<<<
$DISK
EOF

wait

} > /tmp/output.csv
exit;
```

Comment: This is okay. But can we put it like SIZE in a column and USED SPACE in one column and AVAILABLE SPACE in another?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more advanced daily statistics and history you can use a tool such as http://diskreport.net in crontab